# GROUP BY CLAUSE USE

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table with different payment method types: CHECK, MONEY ORDER, CASH. I need to show the break down of different payment types, following is my query. Could anyone suggest or comment how to do it optimally.

```
select 
  COUNT(T3.PAY_METHOD), 
  T1.CLAIM_ID
from TB1 T3 
JOIN TB2 T2 ON T3.CLAIM_ID = T2.CLAIM_ID
GROUP BY T3.PAYMENT_METHOD_CD
```

Following  is output column should look

```
|CHECK|MONEY ORDER|CASHIER'S CHECK|CASH|CREDIT CARD|
```

Displays the total count of all payments received via CHECK that were applied to the specific LIABLE INDIVIDUAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need the output as columns, then you will want to use a SUM(case when method = '' then 0 else 1 end) type solution.  Like this.

```
select t1.claim_id, 
       sum(case when t3.pay_method = 'CASH' then 1 else 0 end) as "CASH",
       sum(case when t3.pay_method = 'MONEY ORDER' then 1 else 0 end) as "MONEY ORDER",
       sum(case when t3.pay_method = 'CHECK' then 1 else 0 end) as "CHECK",
  T1.CLAIM_ID
from TB1 T3 
JOIN TB2 T2 ON T3.CLAIM_ID = T2.CLAIM_ID
GROUP BY T1.CLAIM_ID
```

But it would be much simpler if you just want them each as rows.

```
select T1.CLAIM_ID, T3.PAY_METHOD, COUNT(*)
from TB1 T3 
JOIN TB2 T2 ON T3.CLAIM_ID = T2.CLAIM_ID
GROUP BY T1.CLAIM_ID, T3.PAY_METHOD
```

Comment: Thanks, I just wonder if I can use Rank() function over payment method, any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

sql would be:

```
select T3.PAY_METHOD
, COUNT(T3.PAY_METHOD) records
from TB1 T3 
JOIN TB2 T2 ON T3.CLAIM_ID = T2.CLAIM_ID
GROUP BY T3.PAY_METHOD
```

You can use application code to format the output.